# Creating a subdomain in Apache

Tags: ubuntu, dns, apache2, virtualhost, subdomain

So my default file in apache2/sites-available is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/leaguenotes
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And i want to have a subdomain cms.leaguenotes.com that would clearly lead to my cms folder and here is my cms.leaguenotes.com.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName cms.leaguenotes.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cms.leaguenotes
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And then I also did sudo a2ensite cms.leaguenotes.com and service apache2 restart and unfortunately nothing shows up when I go to cms.leaguenotes.com (I've added folder and added index with an example)

Comment: Do you have a NameVirtualHost *:80?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Run `apachectl configtest` and make sure there are no errors. If there are fix them, then repeat.

Step 2: Ensure your domain is pointing to the right DNS server. Ping it and check the IP coming back is right. You may just have to wait for added subdomain to have it's DNS propagate.

Step 3: Check the error log for hints.